# How to handle concurrent insert to DB, if insert depends on previous record?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, ef-core-2.2

I am designing kind of small banking system (there will be 'credits', not real money). If user has new transaction, I want kind of TransactionLog table to get a record, but I need this record to have to fields "CreditsBefore" and "CreditsAfter".

Considering situation:

```
UserId | Transaction | CreditsBefore | CreditsAfter
1      | +20         | 0             | 20
1      | +5          | 20            | 25
```

imagine that there are 2 new transactions for user "1". The expected result is:

```
UserId | Transaction | CreditsBefore | CreditsAfter
1      | +20         | 0             | 20
1      | +5          | 20            | 25
1      | +10         | 25            | 35
1      | +100        | 35            | 135
```

but if they will be executed in parallel we may end up with:

```
UserId | Transaction | CreditsBefore | CreditsAfter
1      | +20         | 0             | 20
1      | +5          | 20            | 25
1      | +10         | 25            | 35
1      | +100        | 25 [bug]      | 125 [bug]
```

I know that I can use table lock, however I don't want to lock the whole table (it may contain millions of records, for thousands of users).

Is it possible to somehow lock table just for "all records for user with id 1"?
Or is there any other pattern to handle the above scenario?

I am using EF Core and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how this looks in your ORMs, but the simplest technique for that is

- **“pessimistic locking”**:

  At the start of the transaction, lock *the row* (not the whole table) with

  ```
    SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
  ```

  Then transactions that try to modify the same account are serialized, and no anomalies can happen.
- The other alternative is to use **“optimistic locking”**.

  That is most conveniently done using `REPEATABLE READ` transactions. If two transactions try to read and then modify the same account concurrently, one of them will receive a *serialization error*.

  Your software has to be ready to repeat a transaction that receives a serialization error.

Which method is better depends on

1. how well your database API supports the methods
2. how frequently you expect a collision.

   For frequent collisions, pessimistic locking is better, because it avoids the need to frequently repeat transactions (at the price of more locking).